# Steps to follow in creation of a API/library in Java

Tags: java

Trying to construct a common API library using Java. What are the coding standards/conventions to be followed for a API library. I am new to developing a API library, but have implemented Java services with web services ,mq and rdbms.

Comment: Apart from the coding conventions already documented for Java, there are no standards for APIs (Not even the Java libraries are 100% consistent in that regard). There could be many recommendations but most likely they would be supported by opinions and experience.

Comment: Aren't opinions the outcome of expert experience in stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be consistent. Document assumptions. Think about thread safety, security and performance. Use empathy: think of callers to the API's as users, and try to make their lives easier.